# How to convert a pivot-like dataframe values into a heatmap in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn, heatmap

I have made a nested dictionary into a data frame with the following code:

```
pd_dicty = pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(v).T for k, v in list_clusters_vs__layers.items()}, axis=0).T
pd_dicty_nonNaN = pd_dicty.fillna(0)
pd_dicty_nonNaN
```

Then, I got a dataframe like the following wishing to make it into a heatmap:
(each Cluster header has 4 sub headers: #1intermediate_and_meta_  #2proto_  #3_   #4__initial)

```
Cluster_1   Cluster_2   Cluster_3   ... Cluster_13  Cluster_14  Cluster_15
intermediate_and_meta_  proto_  _   __initial   intermediate_and_meta_  proto_  _   __initial   intermediate_and_meta_  proto_  ... _   __initial   intermediate_and_meta_  proto_  _   __initial   intermediate_and_meta_  proto_  _   __initial
AT5G28630   0.29669925  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
AT4G01700   -0.649313413    0   -0.631624688    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
AT2G15490   -0.797255967    -0.935133047    -0.840372303    -0.696443251    0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
AT3G09940   -0.763235517    -0.901562804    -0.806212875    -0.939218417    0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
AT5G51190   0.616816453 0   0.531064945 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
AT3G20550   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.348664291
AT5G67320   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.268064054
AT1G35720   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -1.772985795
AT2G40085   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.428290157
AT5G48560   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -0.337743062
```

That's the code I'm using for trying to making the heatmap using seaborn:

```
hm_from_df = sb.heatmap(pd_dicty_nonNaN, center=0, annot=True)
```

The error output is:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'
```

Does anyone has an idea how to solve this?
Let me know if any other information is needed!
Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

Did this:

```
pd_dicty_nonNaN.info()
```

That is the output, then:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> 
Index: 1306 entries, A----0 to A----0 
Data columns (total 60 columns): 
# Column Non-Null Count Dtype 
--- ------ -------------- -----
.
.
.
dtypes: float64(2), object(58) 
memory usage: 622.4+ KB
```

I'll try now to change objects to float.

**Edit_2:**

```
pd_dicty_nonNaN_ = pd_dicty_nonNaN.astype(float, errors = 'raise')

pd_dicty_nonNaN_.info()


[]out:
dtypes: float64(60)
memory usage: 622.4+ KB
```

Now it works,

```
hm_from_df = sb.heatmap(pd_dicty_nonNaN_, center=0, annot=True)
```

Thanks, @JohanC ! :D

Comment: The error message seems to indicate that some of the data contains strings.  You might want to look at the output of `pd_dicty_nonNaN.info()` to find you non-numeric columns.

Comment: `dype` being `object` means they contain at least one string.  Everything should be numeric for a heatmap.  Please don't add information in the comments, but [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68006302/edit) your post instead.